# How to send ZipInputStream as attachment via java mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, inputstream

I have a `ZipInputStream`. How can we send the `ZipInputStream` as an attachment (data.zip) via java mail?

I had seen some solution like using `ByteArrayDatasource` but since the `MimeBodyPart` receives `InputStream` as one constructor and we have an `InputStream` handy, I would like to know how to solve this issue without using `ByteArrayDataSource`.

Comment: Please add some code (of what you tried), and than we'll be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the data to a file and then attaching the file will definitely work, and if you don't know how large the data might be than that's a reasonable choice.  Otherwise, ByteArrayDataSource will allow you to keep the data in memory, although it will make a copy of the data first.  There are more complicated answers that might have better performance, but those are the two simple approaches.

However, if all you have is a ZipInputStream, I'm not sure there's a way to read the raw zip format data, so I don't think you can use either of these approaches directly.  You either need direct access to the zip file, or you need a real InputStream that contains the zip format data.

(And no, you don't pass the InputStream to the MimeBodyPart constructor since it's not a MIME format entity; you use it to construct a DataSource of some sort, from which you construct a DataHandler, which you set on the MimeBodyPart.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill , I would like to know more about the MIME format entity. What that actually means?. Do you have any references about how MIME body part creates the Attachment.

Comment: As the MimePart javadocs say: The MimePart interface models an Entity as defined by MIME ([RFC2045](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), Section 2.4).  I don't know what you mean by "how MIME body part creates the Attachment".  Are you asking how the attachment is formatted in the MIME message?  See RFC 2045.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a wrong question, what you really want it is:

How can I attach a zip file into a email?

right? You cannot attach any object type you are waiting to attach a InputStream (ZipInputStream in this case) a InputStream is a Stream that allow to read bytes 1 by 1, or by a buffer.

You can use apache commons library commons-io to get a byte array and write those bytes in the filesystem

```
ZipInputStream zis = ...get your stream
byte[] zipbytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(zis);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/temp.zip"));
fos.write(zipbytes);
fos.close();
```

And I found here in the forums just to  copy paste how you can attach the email:

```
final String username = "your.mail.id@gmail.com";
    final String password = "your.password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to.mail.id@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("PFA");

        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        String fileName = "attachmentName.zip"
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File("/path/temp.zip"));
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        System.out.println("Sending");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Daniel , My question was correct only. Due to the performance issue , i don't want to convert my stream into a file and send it as attachment. I read this Zip from a blob stored in data base , At this point of time i have a ZipInputStream , With out being converted to a ByteArrayDataSouce I would like to create the MimeBodyPart. This more over a learning experience ..